# No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query] to type

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to query a two tables by using a join and passing a date value to the Data I want from Postman, but every time I end up getting the error

> No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.burn.promise_to_pay.pojo.PromisePojo]
> at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322) ~[spring-core-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]

this is my first table

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "promiseto_pay")
public class PromiseData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="account_name")
    private String accName;

    @Column(nullable=false)
    private  String paidbyaccountno;

    @Column (name= "mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;

    @Column(name="promised_date")
    private LocalDate promisedDate;

    @Column(name="promised_amount")
    private double promisedAmt;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "paid_by_account_no")
    private TransactionData transactionData;
    
}
```

this is my other table

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "transactions")
public class TransactionData {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

        @Column (name= "id")
        private int id;

        @Column (name= "amount")
        private double amount;

        @Column (name= "bill_reference_number")
        private String billreferencenumber;

        @Column (name= "env")
        private String env;

        @Column(name= "paid_by_account_no")
        private  String paidbyaccountno;

        @Column (name= "paid_by_channel")
        private String paidbychannel;

        @Column (name= "paid_by_name")
        private String paidbyname;

        @Column (name= "raw_payment_request")
        private String rawpaymentrequest;

        @Column (name= "state")
        private String state;

        @Column (name= "transaction_date")
        private LocalDate transactiondate;

        @Column (name= "transaction_id")
        private String transactionid;

        @Column (name= "transaction_type")
        private String transactiontype;

        @Column (name= "created_on")
        private LocalDateTime createdon;

        @Column (name= "updated_on")
        private LocalDateTime updatedon;

        @Column (name= "office_id")
        private double officeid;


}
```

this is my Pojo class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PromisePojo {

    private double amount;
    private String transactionDate;
    private String paidbyaccountno;
    private String paidbyname;
}
```

this is my repository code

```
  @Query("select t.amount, t.transactiondate,p.paidbyaccountno," +
            "t.paidbyname FROM TransactionData t INNER JOIN PromiseData p ON p.paidbyaccountno = t.paidbyaccountno " +
            "where p.promisedDate =? 1")
    List<PromisePojo> fetchByPromisedDate(@Param("promisedDate") LocalDate promisedDate);
```

and this is my controller

```
 @GetMapping("/getbylastdate/{promisedDate}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PromisePojo>> getByPaymentsDate(@PathVariable("promisedDate") LocalDate promisedDate ) {
        try {
            List<PromisePojo> promiseData = promiseDataRepository.fetchByPromisedDate(promisedDate);
            if (promiseData.isEmpty()) {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(promiseData, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

What could I be doing wrong as I have my mapped the output pojo class that should be used to render the data to the end user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projections works a little bit different. If you want to create PromisePojo for each row you need to create your obj manually in query:

```
select new com.burn.promise_to_pay.pojo.PromisePojo(t.amount,transactiondate,p.paidbyaccountno,t.paidbyname) <rest query>
```

your error description talk about it:
No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.burn.promise_to_pay.pojo.PromisePojo

remember to pass the arguments in the correct order

Comment: Hi @notAppp what do you mean tp pass the arguments in the correct order am lost?